# Jquery mobile image zoom functionality on swipe

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, zooming

I am having a zoom functionality working fine in desktop. I need to implement the same in mobile browser on which when I move over the touch screen that particular portion should be zoomed out.
Example 
http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/magnifying-glass-for-images-using-jquery-and-css3

Any comments are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Hi there I recently wrote a plugin that I believe does just this...The difference being that the zoomed in image is not directly under your finger because that would just not make sense.  Try it out I'd love to hear your comments:

https://github.com/Likwidt/spyglasstouch